# Google Slides refresh without exiting Presentation mode

Tags: google-slides

It's something that I hate having to do in the middle of presentation, but someone updates a slide and asks me to refresh so I have to exit out of presentation mode then go back in. Is there a way while still in presentation mode to just press a key that will refresh the slide if it has been updated?

Comment: I made a script that updates a shape in master with current time, and I'm having the same problem: it does not updates in presentation mode. So, it's not just when someone changes (which is rare), it kills some interesting possible addons.